# usedGas comparison: `push()` a struct into the array vs change all the values on the same struct that is stored in the array

Tags: contract-development, gas, mapping, struct

**[Q]** When I `push()` a new struct into an array *vs.* when change all the values inside the same struct that is stored in the array, they both consume different `usedGas`. Regarding this difference, which path should I take, in order to use gas efficiently:

```
node[] array_1;
function foo(){
    array_1.push(<some_value>);
}
```

or

```
uint32 index=0;
node[<array_size>] array_2;
function foo() {
   array_2[index++].value = <some_value>;
}
```

**[Observation]** When I `push()` a new struct into my array, it uses much less `gas` than when I change all the values inside the same struct that is stored in the array.

Why do they differ on `gas` usage since both do the same operations? I assume, I am doing something wrong.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features:

> .push() for Dynamic Storage Arrays 
>   PT Dynamically-sized storage arrays have a member function push, such
>   that var l = arr.push(el); is equivalent to arr[arr.length++] = el;
>   var l = arr.length;.

In this following example: you could see the different `gas` usage.

```
my_contract.transact().push_me( 30, 40, 16 ); consumes 63146 gas
my_contract.transact().change( 30, 40, 16 );  consumes 79468 gas
```

-

```
contract Example {
  struct node { 
    uint32 blk_start;
    uint32 blk_end;
    uint16 core;
    uint32 next; 
   }
   node[]    array_1;
   node[10]  array_2;
   uint32 index = 0;

   function push_me( uint32 blk_start_, uint32 blk_end_, uint16 core_ ) {
     array_1.push(node( { blk_start: blk_start_, blk_end: blk_end_, core: core_, next: 10 }));
   }

   function change( uint32 blk_start_, uint32 blk_end_, uint16 core_ ) {
     array_2[index].core       = core_;
     array_2[index].blk_start = blk_start_;
     array_2[index].blk_end   = blk_end_;
     array_2[index].next      = 10;
     index++;
   }
}
```

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I'm suspecting it's because in `change()`, you actually access that one node several times in a row. Each time, it's going to have to look it up again, and it's probably not helping the optimizer, either.

I tried the following code with the above contract:

```
function change2(uint32 blk_start_, uint32 blk_end_, uint16 core_) {
   array_2[index] = node(blk_start_, blk_end_, core_, 10);
   index++;       
}
```

Here are the results from browser-solidity:

`change`: 56541 gas.

`change2`: **41285 gas**.

`pushme`: 56316 gas.

So I'd say that was the issue.

EDIT: The above numbers are incorrect!

It appears that the first transaction to either `pushme` or `change` costs extra gas, because it increments the index (and therefore adds to storage.) Here are more accurate numbers:

`change`: 41563 gas.

`change2`: **41285 gas.**

`pushme`: 41316 gas.

As you can see, there's almost no difference in the end, even if change2 is slightly better. This is possibly due to the optimizer working behind the scenes. I suggest `pushme`, if for no other reason than you can have unlimited nodes if needed, and it's less code.

Comment: As I understand accessing to memory is expensive. So in your solution you assign the node into the memory in one call instead of multiple calls as I did. But why now `change2` consume less gas than `pushme`, shouldn't they be equal?

Comment: I discovered there was a flaw in my answer, which explains this. The reason it consumes slightly less gas in the end is probably due to whatever assembly-level optimization differences exist between .push() and lookups.

Comment: Did not get the second part (accurate numbers), are those the ones without incrementing the index? No matter what shouldn't incrementation take place? @Matthew Schmidt

Comment: The first time index is incremented, it turns a zero into a one, which is considered increasing the amount of storage a contract uses. This is, IIRC, 4x the gas price of writing to storage that is already non-zero.